# node js : why can't I write asynchronously in jason.js and then read it synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

Please can anyone help me with this? 
my question is: why can't I write asynchronously in jason.js and then read it synchronously?

To make my question clear, here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var originalNote = {
   title: 'todo list',
   body : `that's my secret`
};

var stringNote = JSON.stringify(originalNote);

//here I write asynchronously into my note.json file
fs.writeFile('note.json',stringNote, () => {
       console.log('hey there');
});

//here I read synchronously from the note.json file
var file = fs.readFileSync('./note.json');
var note = JSON.parse(file);
```

when I do this I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yosra/Desktop/notes-node/playground/json.js:31:18)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)

at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)

at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)

at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)

at startExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:276:5)
```

but when I make everything synchronous it works.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you understand what "asynchronously" means? The `.writeFile()` function call returns *immediately*, before the file has actually been written.

Comment: @Pointy yes, synchronous code is executed in a linear way which is not the case for asynchonous code.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback                         
     I may be wrong, but here they say that it doesn't return immediatly

Comment: "Asynchronously writes data to a file" — that means it returns immediately. The callback is invoked when the operation completes.

Comment: ooh yeah, of course thank you so much, I get it now :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

As for your questions, you are not handling async code correctly. your read should happen AFTER your write, so you should do the below:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var originalNote = {
   title: 'todo list',
   body : `that's my secret`
};

var stringNote = JSON.stringify(originalNote);

//here I write asynchronously into my note.json file
fs.writeFile('note.json',stringNote, () => {
       console.log('hey there');
       //here I read synchronously from the note.json file
       var file = fs.readFileSync('./note.json');
       var note = JSON.parse(file);
});
```

Comment: you are welcome. Can you please mark this as the answer so other folks may benefit? or select @Nicks answer from above. seems he and I answered at the same time (just about)

Answer (score 0):

You want to try to read the file *after* it's written. That means you have to do it in the callback function of `writeFile`.

```
//here I write asynchronously into my note.json file
fs.writeFile('note.json',stringNote, () => {
    console.log('hey there');
    //here I read synchronously from the note.json file
    var file = fs.readFileSync('./note.json');
    var note = JSON.parse(file);

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much I get it now